# Get Current full date in Date-Fns in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I need to display the current date using `date-fns`. I wanted the output to be like: `Wednesday July 17, 2020`.

Here's my code below

```
{format(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this format (tested with date-fns v2.15.0)

As the [doc](https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/format):

> `cccc`: Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday
>
> `LLLL`: January, February, ..., December
>
> `d`: 1, 2, ..., 31
>
> `yyyy`: 0044, 0001, 1900, 2017

```js
format(new Date(), "cccc LLLL d, yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible that you can put a `<br>` between `cccc` and `LLLL`?

Comment: @Joseph a safe way to do that (to avoid format collision) is to inject a separator and then replace that by what you want `format(new Date(), "cccc|LLLL d, yyyy").replace('|', '<br>')`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. However I tried this and it works  
`{format(new Date(), `cccc`)}
            <br />
            {format(new Date(), `LLLL d, yyyy`)}`.  I don't know if there is a better way than this. Anyway tnx